# Manipular eventos do windows usando Python

Tags: python

Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação em Python com Pop-up's no Windows (como o Avast, por exemplo). No caso, minha aplicação será um keylogger que pegará uma string de um leitor de código de barras. Quando o keylogger detectar o código, um pop-up surgirá com as informações do boleto.

Que ferramenta do Python eu posso utilizar para manipular este evento?

Comment: Procure por "python desktop notification". [Nessa pergunta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2240674/520779), por exemplo, há algumas opções - dentre elas [uma multi-plataforma](http://code.google.com/p/readertray/source/browse/trunk/readergui.py) que parece bem simples (usa o `wx` que, se não me engano, vem incluída no Python). Nunca usei pessoalmente entretanto, por isso não saberia avaliar se é boa ou não.

Comment: A propósito, aqui no StackOverflow nós normalmente não utilizamos saudações e agradecimentos nas perguntas, daí a sugestão de edição. Veja [esse post no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/846/215) para mais detalhes. P.S. Uma coisa não está clara na sua pergunta: é só notificações ao usuário que você está interessado, ou tem mais coisa? (ex.: chamadas de API, manipulação de registro, COM, MFC...) "Eventos do windows" me parece um pouco genérico demais, poderia por favor editar sua pergunta colocando mais detalhes?

Comment: Ok, desculpe pelo transtorno. Adicionei mais detalhes a minha pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por se tratar de uma script que rodará no Windows, pode ser utilizado a função [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx) para mostrar o *popup*.

Exemplo:

```
from win32api import *
from win32gui import *
import win32con
import sys, os
import struct
import time

class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # Também poderia especificar uma wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Criar a Janela.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( sys.path[0], "balloontip.ico" ))
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
           hicon = LoadImage(hinst, iconPathName, \
                    win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
        except:
          hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "tooltip")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",msg,200,title))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)
        time.sleep(10)
        DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0)

def balloon_tip(title, msg):
    w=WindowsBalloonTip(title, msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    balloon_tip("Título para o pop-up", "Corpo da mensagem aqui!")
```

<sub>[`Fonte`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15921588/1608936)</sub>

Em relação a captura de teclas, você pode usar o [`PyHook`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook), é um *wrapper* que permite que seja feito a técnica de [Hooking](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) através de um *script* em Python, além de poder manipular os eventos do teclado, pode-se alterar o comportamento dos eventos do mouse.

O exemplo abaixo captura as teclas digitadas e imprime na tela.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pyHook
import pythoncom

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
        print event.Ascii

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()

while True:
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Para encerrar basta pressionar as teclas <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Eu já fiz uma aplicação em python que captura e envia eventos do windows, no meu caso do teclado e mouse e utilizei o [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Apesar do nome tem versão para python 64 bit também.

A biblioteca é basicamente um binding, pode ter coisa que você vai ter que ver a documentação da api do windows para C e definir as constantes no seu codigo.

Para instalar recomendo que você baixe o instalador do site dele, escolha a ultima versão da biblioteca e a versão compatível com o seu python (eg: 2.7 64 bit)

Para instalar dentro de um virtualenv você pode usar o easy_install e passar o path local do instalador.exe ou a url.